# How to order an array using Magento's Position box

Tags: php, magento, fishpig

I am using Magento and WordPress so have gone for the FishPig Module. I have a CMS Page and am using the assocaited blog posts tab to select posts to show on this page which is all working as expected.

The problem I am facing is when I try to use the position box in Magento next to each post selected they always stay in the same order on the frontend no matter what order I set them as.

I know in Magentos Categories you can use the same position boxes to order how the products show on that specific category so I am wanting to use the same function for the code below to order the blog posts but I cant find out how to get it working.

```
    <?php if (($posts = $this->getPostCollection()) !== false): ?>
    <?php if (count($posts) > 0): ?>
        <div class="box-collateral box-description" style="padding:5px 20px;">
            <!--<?php if ($title = $this->getTitle()): ?>
                <h2 style="margin-bottom:15px;">Blog <span style="color: #68d088;">Posts</span></h2>

            <?php endif; ?>-->
            <div class="std">
                <ul>
                <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
                    <li class="related-blogs">
                        <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>"><h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?></h2></a>
                        <div class="content">
                            <?php 
                                $pos = strpos($post['post_content'], ' ', 300);
                                echo substr($post['post_content'],0,$pos );
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <a style="color:#68d088; font-weight:bold;" href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>">Read More...</a>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you associating posts or associating categories? If you're using categories, these can't be positioned but the postioning should work fine on just posts.

Comment: @BenTideswell I am associating posts from a CMS Page